# How to use PyPDF2 to extract all the text from a .pdf file and return it as a STRING?

Tags: python, io, pypdf

I have a single page .pdf [document](https://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/courtorders/120417zr_4gd5.pdf) and I want to extract the string:

'               \n    \n   \n         \n     (ORDER LIST:  583 U.S.) \nMONDAY, DECEMBER 4, 2017 \nORDER IN PENDING CASE \n17A550 TRUMP, PRESIDENT OF U.S., ET AL. V. HAWAII, ET AL. \nThe application for a stay presented to Justice Kennedy and by \nhim referred to the Court is granted, and the District Court™s \nOctober 20, 2017 order granting a preliminary injunction is stayed \npending disposition of the Government™s appeal in the United States \nCourt of Appeals for the Ninth Circuit and disposition of the \nGovernment™s petition for a writ of certiorari, if such writ is \n\nsought.  If a writ of certiorari is sought and the Court denies the \npetition, this order shall terminate automatically. If the Court \ngrants the petition for a writ of certiorari, this order shall \nterminate when the Court enters its judgment. \nIn light of its decision to consider the case on an expedited \nbasis, we expect that the Court of Appeals will render its decision \n\nwith appropriate dispatch.  \nJustice Ginsburg and Justice Sotomayor would deny the \napplication. \n'

So far I have written:

```
def text_from_pdf_url(url):
    text = ''
    data = requests.get(url).content
    data_as_file = io.BytesIO(data)
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(data_as_file)
```

I'm really lost on the last step, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You want `extractText()`:

```
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('test.pdf', 'rb')
p = reader.getPage(0)
text = p.extractText()
print text
```

Please, be aware `extractText()` is not always reliable and can work poorly for some PDF files, depending on the generator used.